# How to detect if a ListView in WPF would need scrolling?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, wpf-listview

I have several items in a list view in WPF. I'm wanting to add some items to the next "page" when they reach beyond the viewing area. However, I don't want scrolling available. I disable the scrolling.

```
<ListView ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
```

I don't want scrolling at all, I only want to know if there are items beyond the scrolling. Currently I limit the list by number of items on the page, however my items are not same size nor would I know the size of the screen so this needs to be adjustable.

Comment: Can you show the entire XAML code?

Comment: Maybe you can change to `ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"` but change the width to zero or one. This way you could use the `IsVisibilityChanged` event.

Comment: @RolandDeschain I thought about making the scrollbar match the background, but I think I like your idea better. Trying to look for a better solution.

Comment: Just for my general understanding. You really just want to know, if your "page" is full of items, right? Are the items of same size? You could add the size of the items and compare them to the listview size (+ maybe margin/padding).

Comment: @RolandDeschain, the items are not of the same size. Is it possible to add all the sizes of the items and see if they are listview size what about padding margins?

Answer (score 0):

Although this is a solution and works, it doesn't appear to be good on performance **need another answer**.

In order to speed up performance I now
tempNumItemsPerPage = tempNumItemsPerPage -2;

1) Added an Event handler for the scrollchange in the constructor

```
public ViewName()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // Handler to add scroll change event
    Items.AddHandler(ScrollViewer.ScrollChangedEvent, new ScrollChangedEventHandler(Items_ScrollChanged));

    Init();            
}
```

2) Added the Event onto my listview

```
<ListView ScrollViewer.ScrollChanged="OrderItems_ScrollChanged">
```

3) Add the scrollchanged code

```
private void OrderItems_ScrollChanged(object sender, ScrollChangedEventArgs scrollChangedEventArgs)
{
    ScrollViewer scrollViewer = Extensions.WPFExtensions.GetChildOfType<ScrollViewer>(Items);

    if (scrollViewer.ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility == Visibility.Visible)
    {
        GetItemsOnPage();

        tempNumItemsPerPage--;               
    }
}
```

The only issue I have is it resets the page everytime seeing if the scrollbar is off [not visible to the eye].

```
public static class WPFExtensions
{
    public static T GetChildOfType<T>(this DependencyObject depObj)
        where T : DependencyObject
    {
        if (depObj == null) return null;

        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
        {
            var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);

            var result = (child as T) ?? GetChildOfType<T>(child);
            if (result != null) return result;
        }

        return null;

    }
}
```